# Merge two rows into one and sum a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**THIS IS NOT ASKING HOW TO USE SUM() AND GROUP BY**

I have two rows in tableA

```
ID VALUE
1  100
1  200
```

I want tableA:

```
ID VALUE
1  300
```

Note that I want to

1. delete the original two records in tableA
2. and replace them by the new record in tableA

Is this related to `merge` function?

I only want to work on tableA, don't want to create any new tables.

Comment: Assuming that there may be other, similar rows in tableA, do you want to carry this out for all rows in tableA (gather and sum by ID, deleting all constituent rows)?

Comment: I don't think that this is related to `MERGE`.  `MERGE` is used to merge two different sets of data.

Comment: No, this isn't related to `MERGE` at all.  You could pull the results into a temp table using `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`, and use that to delete/update your table.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Yes, I want to aggregate by all qualified rows and delete and replace them.

Comment: Can you use temp table to copy your desired data than delte your desired rows and insert the new data?

Answer (score 2):

How about `MERGE`:

```
;with cte as (
    select t.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as rn,
    sum(value) over (partition by id) as total_value
    from your_table t
)
merge into cte as t
using cte as t2
on (
    t.id = t2.id
    and t.rn = t2.rn
    and t.rn = 1
)
when matched then update set t.value = t2.total_value
when not matched by source then delete;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/RUR96675)

Comment: Nice solution  +1

Comment: @John . . . Thanks :-)